# Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permission, Error 500.19 (0x80070005)

Tags: asp.net, iis

So i'm having this error for 2 days looking for an solution but nothing works...

What it says is this:

[https://gyazo.com/4cd854b40ea311d8c9f81f401ae901bf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKOGu.png)

I've tried these methods but they don't work:

1. Click Properties.
2. Click the Security tab, and then click Edit.
3. Click Add.
4. In the Enter the object names to select box, type  computername\IIS_IUSRS, click Check Names, and then click OK.
5. Note Computername is a placeholder for the computer name.
   Click to select the Read check box, and then click OK.
   In the Properties dialog box for the folder, click OK.

--

The web.config file is an XML file would that be a problem?

I've tried many other forums and websites and even contacted microsoft but nothing seems to fix it.

As of the IIS_USRS i cant seem to find it. But i read that it's the same as an admin account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think IIS has access to the `/{user}/desktop` folder. Better put it where the permissions are already set, like the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\{yoursite}` folder

Comment: Can't select it from inetpub since it's only possible to select the folder from user accounts

Comment: Then you probably need more privileges on your user account or a dedicated test server for websites.

Comment: I've a user account that has admin privileges and i have a website hoster if that is what you mean

Comment: Try giving `everyone` access for testing. If it works you know you need more privileges.

Comment: Somehow when i redirect it towards the hosted website it still opens it in localhost with the port that i used within IIS.

So i think that nobody really can access it but me./////////